# Trying to do basic subtraction from a database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, math

I'm trying to subtract data based on user input, for example:

```
**id  |  quantity
  1   |  50
  2   |  30
  3   |  60**
```

**UPDATE *table* SET quantity=quantity - * some input value***

This is easy if I'm subtracting field by field, ***where id=1...2...3***, but I want to subtract values automatically when I input quantity, so if **input is 60**, and there is **50 in the first field**, remainder would be subtracted from next field, and so on, like this:

**$input = 60;**
Now first quantity will be 50-60=0, mod=10, second 30-10=20.

```
**id  |  quantity
  1   |  0
  2   |  20
  3   |  60**
```

Can someone help me? I tried everything I could remember.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the new values using:

```
select t.*,
       (case when running_quantity - quantity >= 60 then 0
             when running_quantity > 60 then running_quantity - quantity
             else quantity
        end) as new_quantity
from (select t.*, sum(quantity) over (order by id) as running_quantity
      from t
     ) t
```

You can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
             (case when running_quantity - quantity >= 60 then 0
                   when running_quantity > 60 then running_quantity - quantity
                   else quantity
              end) as new_quantity
       from (select t.*, sum(quantity) over (order by id) as running_quantity
             from t
            ) t
       ) tt
       on tt.id = t.id
    set quantity = new_quantity
    where new_quantity <> quantity;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this will help!

Comment: New here, sry, I accepted your answer :)
Thanks once again!